# Get dates between 2 sets of dates excluding non workdays

Tags: vba, function, date

I am using a function to get dates between 2 sets of dates, it works, however I would like to only get dates that are workdays:

Have tried incorporating
Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay but I am still getting non workdays in the set of dates - any suggestions?

Original function:

```
Public Function getDates(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As Variant

    Dim varDates()      As Date
    Dim lngDateCounter  As Long

    ReDim varDates(0 To CLng(EndDate) - CLng(StartDate))

    For lngDateCounter = LBound(varDates) To UBound(varDates)
        varDates(lngDateCounter) = CDate(StartDate)
        StartDate = CDate(CDbl(StartDate) + 1)
    Next lngDateCounter

    getDates = varDates

End Function
```

Trial to exclude non workdays:

```
Public Function getDates(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As Variant

    Dim varDates()      As Date
    Dim lngDateCounter  As Long

    ReDim varDates(0 To CLng(EndDate) - CLng(StartDate))

    For lngDateCounter = LBound(varDates) To UBound(varDates)
        varDates(lngDateCounter) = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(StartDate, 0))
        StartDate = CDate(CDbl(StartDate) + 1)
    Next lngDateCounter

    getDates = varDates

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

The collections for holidays (fixed and floating) are initialized with hard coded dates but it would be better if the dates were read from a worksheet or table.

```
Private mFixedHolidays As Collection
Private mFloatingHolidays As Collection

Public Function getDates(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As Variant

    Dim varDates()      As Date
    Dim lngDateCounter  As Long

    ReDim varDates(0 To CLng(EndDate) - CLng(StartDate))
    
    Dim dTotalWorkdays As Long
    dTotalWorkdays = 0
    
    Dim dDate As Date
    
    dDate = StartDate
    For lngDateCounter = LBound(varDates) To UBound(varDates)
        
        If Not (IsWeekendDay(dDate) Or IsFixedHoliday(dDate) Or IsFloatingHoliday(dDate)) Then
            varDates(dTotalWorkdays) = dDate
            dTotalWorkdays = dTotalWorkdays + 1
        End If
        
        dDate = CDate(CDbl(dDate) + 1)
        
    Next lngDateCounter

    ReDim Preserve varDates(dTotalWorkdays - 1)
    
    getDates = varDates

End Function

Private Function IsWeekendDay(ByVal dateOfInterest As Date) As Boolean
    IsWeekendDay = _
         Weekday(dateOfInterest) = VbDayOfWeek.vbSaturday _
              Or Weekday(dateOfInterest) = VbDayOfWeek.vbSunday
End Function

Private Function IsFixedHoliday(ByVal dateOfInterest As Date) As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = False
    
    If mFixedHolidays Is Nothing Then
        Set mFixedHolidays = New Collection
        'Year portion of dates will be ignored
        With mFixedHolidays
            .Add "7/4/2022"
            .Add "12/25/2022"
            .Add "1/1/2022"
            'Add other fixed date holidays
        End With
    End If
    
    Dim fixedDate As Date
    Dim dateToken As Variant
    For Each dateToken In mFixedHolidays
        
        fixedDate = DateValue(dateToken)
        
        If Month(fixedDate) = Month(dateOfInterest) And Day(fixedDate) = Day(dateOfInterest) Then
            result = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    IsFixedHoliday = result
    
End Function

Private Function IsFloatingHoliday(ByVal dateOfInterest As Date) As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = False
    
    If mFloatingHolidays Is Nothing Then
        Set mFloatingHolidays = New Collection
        With mFloatingHolidays
            .Add "5/30/2022" 'Memorial Day
            'Add other floating date holidays
        End With
    End If
    
    Dim floatingDate As Date
    Dim dateToken As Variant
    For Each dateToken In mFloatingHolidays
        
        floatingDate = DateValue(dateToken)
        
        If floatingDate = dateOfInterest Then
            result = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    IsFloatingHoliday = result
    
End Function
```

Comment: Tested your function, works well thanks. I realized I should exclude holidays as well, was trying to do that from workday function, any idea how to incorporate that?

Comment: @Florian Added code for fixed and floating holidays.  Of course, supporting holidays will require some amount of annual maintenance.  Try to design your process such that the  maintenance is done to an external data store (file, worksheet, or table) rather than your code.

Comment: appreciate the help, in fact tested in a different context, and seems there is an issue with the declaration of `Private mFixedHolidays As Collection` and  `Private mFloatingHolidays As Collection` have tried moving them around but shows an error "invalid attribute in sub or function"

Comment: The declarations must precede any Function or Sub in the module.

Comment: ok didnt know that, what's the advantage vs normal dim declarations? Also ran into another issue, if the 2 dates from get dates are the same day & are a `mFloatingHolidays` then the subscript runs out of range on `ReDim Preserve varDates(dTotalWorkdays - 1)` because `dTotalWorkdays = 0` i think?

Comment: Regarding the error I mentioned above, it's actually not related to the function, just need to do some error checking on dates before using it..

Comment: Dim declarations are typically only used within Functions and Subs.  When used this way, the declared value/object has ‘Procedure’ scope.  Objects/values declared as Private have ‘Module’ scope and can be referenced by all procedures in the module.  VBA requires that all ‘Module’ scope declarations precede all procedures in the module.